# Python - attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python

With the following folder structure:

```
foo.py
dir/
   bar.py
```

I'm trying to import a function in `foo.py` from `bar.py`, like so:

**bar.py**

```
from ..foo import func
```

**foo.py**

```
def func():
   pass
```

But I get:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

---

How do I do this?

ps: `__init__.py` files are there at both levels, but omitted.

Comment: Not sure the answer, but happy to vote up the question, given a nice minimal reproducible example and a question of likely generic usefulness to other people.

Comment: @alani thanks. feel free to give your answer.

Comment: leminhnguyenHUST's answer will work for you if modified by what I wrote as a comment. (In its current form, it will only work if the current directory is the parent directory of `root`.)

Comment: How are you running bar.py when you get that error? Is it a top level script or is it imported by something else?

Answer (score 1):

suppose that you have the structure likes this:

```
root/
   foo.py
   dir2/
      bar.py
```

In `bar.py` you can do as the following:

```
import sys
path = "the/absolute/path/to/root"
sys.path.append(path)
from foo import func

# your code here
```

Comment: Your use of `"root"` is problematic, because it makes assumptions about the process's current working directory. How about something relative to `__file__`, such as `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')` or `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`?

Comment: yes, you can. It's a good idea. But when you run the code on `vscode` the use of `root` is enough efficient

Answer (score 0):

i use [repackage](https://pypi.org/project/repackage/0.5/) for this issue

```
pip install repackage


import repackage
repackage.up()
from foo import func
```

Repackage can make relative imports very easy in a wide range of cases